# Handle event in splitter area of splitcontainer control

Tags: c#, .net, events, splitcontainer

Is there any trivial way to handle click event on the splitter area of the **WinFroms splitcontainer** control? (***symbolized by blue in my picture***) E.g. I'd like to collapse panel1 by double clicking this area.

Or another possibility to put some nice button in this area and by clicking it I can collapse panels.

I don't wanna  great hack to make a soulution, it would be nice to have a trivial one.

Thx

(.net 4/c#/VS2010)

[image]

Comment: This question can easily be answered in MSDN documentation, as the answers below suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `SplitContainer.DoubleClick` event for this purpose..

```
  splitContainer1.DoubleClick += splitContainer1_DoubleClick;
```

and

```
    private void splitContainer1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;
    }
```

If you want the location of the click, use `MouseDoubleClick` event which comes with `MouseEventArgs` for the event handler.

Comment: I don't want it. I want collapse only by double clicking of 'splitter area' (symbolized by blue in my pic)

Comment: @Tom the DoubleClick event fires only when you double click on the splitter and not the panels.

Comment: Sorry about that I thought it was fired by anywhere on the container. I confused some things in my code and handled panel double click. Sorry for that I am tired.

Comment: I am trying to implement hide/show left panel  (`Panel1Collapsed`) trigger with `SplitContainer.DoubleClick` event.

Hiding works properly, but I can not show it: V-Splitter is invisible and  event can not be fired.

Is there workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You mean besides the SplitContainer's [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event?

Comment: Click event fires when clicking on the whole area of the container and as I know it does not give information about the exact place of the clicking. I can have point info, but it does not tell me the 'blue' are was clicked.